# how to change gradient fill of a movieClip in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, gradient, colortransform

Let's say I have a complex shaped MovieClip with a gradient color (A -> B) on the stage and I want to change the begin and end colors of the gradient at run-time.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drew this MovieClip with your mouse it is not possible. If you want to do so, you could have your gradient in a rectangle MovieClip with a mask over it. The mask will have the shape of your current gradient. Then in AS3 you could redraw the gradient in the MovieClip (called gradientZone in the example below).

```
var matr:Matrix = new Matrix();
matr.createGradientBox(gradientZone.width, gradientZone.height, 0, 0, 0);
gradientZone.graphics.clear();
gradientZone.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0xFF0000, 0x0000FF], [1, 1], [0x00, 0xFF], matr);        
gradientZone.graphics.drawRect(0,0,gradientZone.width, gradientZone.height);
```